# Which of the following groups are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Which of the following groups are isomorphic?
>   $\mathbb Z_{24}, \mathbb Z_{4}\times \mathbb Z_{6}, S_4,
> A_4\times\mathbb Z_{2}, \mathbb Z_{8}\times \mathbb Z_{3}, D_{12},D_6\times  \mathbb Z_{2}$

I have only found that $\mathbb Z_{24}$ and $ \mathbb Z_{8}\times \mathbb Z_{3}$ are isomorphic. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, they are, this is just the Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commutative groups of order $24$ in your list are $\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$,  $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$. Applying CRT we have $\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}\simeq \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, since $gcd(3,8)=1$. The remaining group here is not isomorphic to it, since it has no element of order $24$.

The other groups are non-commutative, hence different from the commutative ones. $S_4$ has trivial center, but $D_{12}$ has not, so they are not isomorphic. Similarly we see that the remaining groups are different, too.

Alltogether there are $15$ different groups of order $24$. In other words, $9$ groups are still missing in the list, e.g., $Q_8\times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, $SL(2,3)$, etc.